How optimizing Selectize Performance by Centralizing Options Lists?
I'm using the Selectize library and facing a challenge. The page I'm building repeatedly creates the same "select" element with a large list of options, which affects performance. These elements are added dynamically when the page loads.
I want to know if it's possible to link the options list of the duplicated inputs to a "central list" to avoid rendering multiple "selectize-dropdown-content" with the same content. I've researched extensively but couldn't find an easy solution. If necessary, I can create a plugin, although I'm not familiar with the library.
Example:
const Options = [
  { value: 'option1', text: 'Opção 1' },
  { value: 'option2', text: 'Opção 2' },
];

$('#select1').selectize({
  options: Options,
});

$('#select2').selectize({
  options: Options,
});

Result:

These are the same options, no need to load them repeatedly. Ideally, the only resource to maintain would be the uniqueness of each select, such as input, cache...
